# Netstat does not show ports exposed by Docker Windows container

Tags: docker, port, netstat, windows-server-2019

I installed Docker on Windows Server 2019. The version is

Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608.

A container was created to run an instance of SQL server. The container started successfully with the following command.

```
docker run -d -p 1430:1433 test1433
```

I can login the SQL server with "localhost,1430" as connection string.

However `netstat -an` does not show the port. External computers cannot access this port.

I checked [Docker and netstat: netstat is not showing ports, exposed by docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454955/docker-and-netstat-netstat-is-not-showing-ports-exposed-by-docker-containers#:~:text=ANSWER%3A%20This%20is%20related%20to,t%20be%20listed%20by%20netstat) and other URL. However the solutions do not work for me.

Did anyone else encounter the issue?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same on windows but for linux this works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160343/netstat-not-showing-ports-exposed-by-docker?noredirect=1&lq=1